# netbeans jpa customize entity generation from database

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, netbeans, code-generation

I want to use existing active oracle database in my EE project. I try to find a way to generate entity classes from this database with more than 140 tables and many many relations.

I tried many generator wizards in Netbeans and eclipse but the result does not fit my customization requirements. NB `JPA-Modeler` plugin is good tool I've used but i need specific custom config to automate entity generation as i need, without any manual changes for each class/table in diagram.

For example type mapping customization for something like: `NUMBER(1)->Boolean or NUMBER(15)->Long` and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to try minuteproject for the track [JPA2](http://minuteproject.wikispaces.com/JPA2).
It manages many-to-many, one-to-many, many-to-one relationships.

It bundles many customisation at model level (name of entities, columns, relationships) done via [global conventions](http://minuteproject.wikispaces.com/Configuration#Model%20configuration-Business%20Model%20Configuration%20conventions) or entity/column centric enrichment.
It does not have for the moment convention relation related to type mappings, those could be developed via sending a proposal/opening a discussion at (minuteproject@googlegroups.com).

Meanwhile the two mapping configuration required (NUMBER(1)->Boolean or NUMBER(15)->Long) should correspond to the default mapping behavior.

Comment: cant find a way to customize default type mapping behavior in configurations or documentations. 'NUMBER(1) --> Boolean'