# Customize entity generation from database in NetBeans 8

Tags: java, templates, netbeans, code-generation

I already know how to "create entity classes from datatable" and how to use them etc., but the created entity classes does not completely fit my requirements.

For example

- I need to have extra annotations for ID creation to my ID field.
- Fields of Type Number(19,0) should be of Type `Long` instead of `BigDecimal` or similar

I wonder if there is a way to change those entity templates?

In my NetBeans IDE I cannot find a way to do so, so "open in Editor" button is disabled, as you can see below.

[image]

So, is it possibile to change the way those entity classes are created? If yes, where and how to do so?

Answer (score 5):

You can try **minuteproject** check the [documentation](http://minuteproject.wikispaces.com/JPA2).

**MinuteProject** 4 JPA2 generates:
JPA2 entities with annotations, embeddedId classes for composite key. The entities can be generated in java or in groovy.
JPA2 metamodel associated to entities to enable the user to build compilable queries.
Enumeration
Other maven pom.xml, querydsl integration...

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will definitely have a look into it. Nevertheless it is not really an answer to my question, as I was asking for how to modify the mentioned NetBeans plugin and not for alternative approaches. But I guess it might be helpful for other people who are looking into this question anyway, thus take my upvote (+1)

Answer (score 3):

The Netbeans support team have this answer:
https://blogs.oracle.com/NetBeansSupport/entry/why_cannot_some_templates_be

EDITED:
You can right click on a Entity Classes from Database and then you can select copy option, but it does'nt work.

Similar Question: [netbeans jpa customize entity generation from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23539275/netbeans-jpa-customize-entity-generation-from-database)

Comment: Thanks for this hint. Please provide the gist of the linked article in your answer, so I will be able to accept it in consideration of the SO rules. (even if I am not happy to hear this :) )